# How to get data from webpage using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

Hi all am trying to get some table data from webpage. rather than getting all data from web ,i need specific data from table for example URL given below.

https://in.finance.yahoo.com/investing/

there many tables on that webpage.

please give me a solutions to get webpage data from that webpage. just take example of any table from that data.

Comment: Please give us *your* solutions - that currently don't work, describe the problem with them, and we might be able to help

Comment: Correct me if I"m wrong but it sounds like you're trying to hack something, not code something productive.

Comment: @JoeScotto am not trying to hack anything i need data from webpage to notepad. wt i am getting is all HTML pahe in program i need data which is usefull like we see on page not all HTML junk

Comment: @Sayse like code given below   WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("anywebsite");
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            HttpWebResponse response =       (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"D:\xyz.txt", responseFromServer);

Comment: It seems to me like you're trying to get data from a database in Yahoo Finance, that's very very fishy.

Comment: @Sayse Hmm, I just looked into it and it seems like that would be illegal as well. Isn't this considered hacking in a way because it's getting data that wouldn't be normally accessible?

Comment: @JoeScotto sorry i dont have any proof for you. am not working on hacking i just gave example of that website because it has tables

Comment: @JoeScotto - What isn't accessible about it? The op has given you the link straight to it. It may not be moral but its definitely not illegal. Yahoo may even provide their own api to do it. Arjun Parmar, edit your code into your question and explain why it isn't working and what has been done so far to try to fix it

Comment: @Sayse It's just a new concept to me, what would be the purpose of it?

Comment: @JoeScotto you are taking it too much serious. is reading data by eyes called hacking from that website? is writing data on paper, read by eyes called  hacking? if no than reading that same data by programs is also not hacking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) to extract every part of webpage for example table.